# What does "I can see someone's take at least somewhat" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

So here is the context: 
Three people are talking about a subject.
One of them say:

"These things happen. I can see Marie's point of view easily, having been around good universities for a lot of my life; I can see Helena' take at least somewhat."

What does it mean in this case please ?

Comment: Welcome to ell. Would you tell us with which part you have problem. Here, "take" means "opinion".

Comment: This sense of "take" is relatively recent, deriving from the full OED's definition 10: *orig. and chiefly Theatre, Film, and Television. An actor's reaction or response to an action, statement, etc., typically manifested by a particular facial expression, esp. directed to camera or an audience,* first recorded 1938. The first citation for their definition 12: *An individual's interpretation or assessment of a person, thing, or situation; a particular way of regarding or understanding something. Freq. with **on*** is 1977.

Comment: You need an *apostrophe s* with the second name, just like with *Marie's* I edited your question to *Helena's* but maybe you mean *Helen's*?

Answer (score 1):

> I can see Marie's **point of view** easily, having been around good universities for a lot of my life; I can see Helena's (or Helen's) **take** at least somewhat."

The sentence uses *take* to avoid repeating *point of view*. But your sentence needs to use an *apostrophe s* with the second name, just like with the first name: *Marie's*.

As a noun **take** can mean *point of view* or *interpretation*. Several online dictionaries do not list this usage, and Collins lists it as "informal, mainly US." As a native speaker of American English, I can say it's informal but quite idiomatic.

Even in [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/take), you have to go down to the 84th and last entry to find this meaning:

*take* (noun)

> a version or interpretation

But the first 76 definitions of *take* are for the verb, so it's not as uncommon as one might be led to believe.

*At least somewhat* means *to a certain extent*. The speaker doesn't *see* or *understand* "Helena's (?)  take" completely.

Answer (score 0):

see = to understand

I see what you mean.

I don't see the point of your story.

Take = noun to mean someone's point of view, interpretation or assessment; how someone thinks about something.

The sentence means I can understand Helen's point of view to some extent.